# How can I reference values from one dictionary to another dictionary or value in a plist?

Tags: ios

```
 <plist version="1.0">
<key>colors</key>
 <dict>
     <key>color</key>
     <string>f9982f</string>
 </dict>
<key>more_colors</key>
 <dict>
     <key>othercolor</key>
     <string>$color</string>
 </dict>
<key>colorString</key>
<string>$color</string>
</plist>
```

Here is the plist I am working with. I would like other color and the string colorString to have the same value as colors['color'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this with just a plist, you will have to write code to handle these "$" cases in the code you use to look up values in the plist.

```
- (UIColor *)colorForKey:(NSString* )colorKey fromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {


   if ([dictionary[colorKey] containsString:@“$”]) {
      //handle reference to color
  }
}
```